# Embedded timestamp could not be verified for certain TSA

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature, trusted-timestamp

I am getting embedded timestamp could not be verified for TSA : http://timestamp.digicert.com

[image: Embedded timestamp issue]

but with same sample code and TSA : http://ts.quovadisglobal.com/eu . It works fine

I am using PDFBox example for singing a document
https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignatureBase.java

[Signed sample files](https://github.com/nofelkad/pdf-sample)

Comment: For analysis please share an example PDF illustrating the issue.

Comment: I have attached both the files

Comment: I get "403 Forbidden" for both links.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia, "In March 2019, access to Zippyshare was blocked for visitors in the United Kingdom, with a HTTP 403 error message displayed. No reason was given for the block, and it is unclear why Zippyshare decided to block users from the UK.[2] Zippyshare became similarly unavailable in Germany in April 2019[5] and in Spain in June 2019, also with no explanation.[6]" That explains it. According to the same article, Zippyshare has a questionable reputation anyways.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I have uploaded both documents to a GitHub repo and shared the updated link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the trust tabs of the Acrobat time stamp certificate viewer ("Show Signature Properties..." -> "Advanced Properties..." -> "Show Certificate..."), the problem becomes clear:

| not working | working |
| --- | --- |
| [image: not trusted] | [image: trusted] |

As you can read at the top of that tab in case of the working time stamp,

> This certificate is directly trusted in your trusted certificates list. Source of Trust obtained from European Union Trusted Lists (EUTL).

and in case of the not working time stamp,

> This certificate is not trusted.

(If you click through the certificate chain, you'll see the same again and again, *not trusted*.)

Looking into the Adobe Acrobat Trusted Certificates, one currently sees

[image: trusted DigiCert certificates]

So indeed, the G4 DigiCert certificates used to sign your problem time stamp are not trusted by Adobe Acrobat. Thus, Acrobat cannot verify the time stamp.

But have a look at the validity dates of the intermediary certificate and the TSA certificate,

- *DigiCert Trusted G4 RSA4096 SHA256 TimeStamping CA* is valid from 2022/03/23 02:00:00 +02'00' and
- *DigiCert Timestamp 2022 - 2* is valid from 2022/03/29 02:00:00 +02'00'.

They have been issued less then 2 weeks ago! Maybe they simply are *not yet* on the Adobe trust lists (AATL / EUTL). I've seen relevant trust anchors taking months to be included in those lists. Thus, it's not unlikely that Adobe Acrobat will become able to validate those time stamps over time.